# PHP simplexml: why does xpath stop working?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

A strange thing happened after a supplier changed the XML header a bit. I used to be able to read stuff using xpath, but now I can't even get a reply with

```
$xml->xpath('/');
```

They changed it from this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE NewsML SYSTEM "http://www.newsml.org/dl.php?fn=NewsML/1.2/specification/NewsML_1.2.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % nitf SYSTEM "http://www.nitf.org/IPTC/NITF/3.4/specification/dtd/nitf-3-4.dtd">
%nitf;
]>
<NewsML>
...
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<NewsML
  xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/ http://www.iptc.org/std/NewsML/1.2/specification/NewsML_1.2.xsd http://iptc.org/std/NITF/2006-10-18/   http://contentdienst.pressetext.com/misc/nitf-3-4.xsd"
>
...
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely this is because they've introduced a default namespace (`xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/"`) into their document. SimpleXML's support for default namespaces is not very good, to put it mildly.

Can you try to explicitly register a namespace prefix:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("n", "http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/");
$xml->xpath('/n:NewsML');
```

You would have to adapt your XPath expressions to use the `"n:"` prefix on *every* element. Here is some additional info: [http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~felix/xml/php-and-xmlns.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20090414184326/http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~felix/xml/php-and-xmlns.html).

EDIT: As per [the spec](http://php.net/manual/function.simplexml-element-registerXPathNamespace.php):

> [The `registerXPathNamespace()` function](http://php.net/manual/function.simplexml-element-registerXPathNamespace.php) creates a prefix/ns context for the next XPath query.

This means it would have to be called before every XPath query, thus a function to wrap XPath queries would be the natural thing to do:

```php
function simplexml_xpath_ns($element, $xpath, $xmlns)
{
    foreach ($xmlns as $prefix_uri)
    {
        list($prefix, $uri) = explode("=", $prefix_uri, 2);
        $element->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $uri);
    }
    return $element->xpath($xpath);
}
```

Usage:

```php
$xmlns = ["n=http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/"];
$result = simplexml_xpath_ns($xml, '/n:NewsML', $xmlns);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Also, it seems you have to register the namespaces before every single xpath request.. if you could add this to your answer, it'd be perfect ;)

Comment: Thanks... that fixed my XPATH queries of my Google Earth (KML) file. Which would only work if I remove the xmlns attribute from my XML file.

Comment: Why is registering namespaces necessary? Why aren't namespaces just treated as attributes on the root element?

Comment: @Jakobud Because namespaces *aren't* just attributes, they change the entire element. Think of them as… *colors*. Thought experiment: `<foo>` is default (black). `<foo xmlns="rgb(255,0,0)">` sets a new default. Now the entire element (and its descendants!) are red. Now, `xpath('//foo')` will only select black (that's how it works). You must make it recognize red with `registerXPathNamespace("red", "rgb(255,0,0)")`. Now you can do `xpath('//red:foo')`. (Note: `<foo xmlns:red="rgb(255,0,0)">` *leaves the element at the default* but introduces the prefix `red` for later use, i.e. `<red:bar>`.)