# Parsing XML attribute causes silent error

Tags: php, simplexml

Could someone explain to me why $xml2 fails to parse, but $xml3 works? Am I not escaping something within the xml string?

```
$xml2 = "<multistatus xmlns=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">Test</multistatus>";

$xml3 = "<multistatus>Test</multistatus>";

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
//echo $xml;
foreach ($root->xpath('//multistatus') as $node) {
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}
```

Ok, this is the latest copy with the requested modifications and it still does not appear to work:

```
$xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus xmlns=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">Test</multistatus>";

$xml3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus>Test</multistatus>";

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
$root->registerXPathNamespace("n", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav");
//echo $xml;
foreach ($root->xpath('//n:multistatus') as $node) {
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem probably comes from this not being a well formed XML string. Both simplxmlelement and simplexml_load_string both require well formed XML strings. Try adding normal XML headers to see if that helps.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0">
<root>
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">Test</multistatus>
</root>
XML;
```

Comment: $xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus xmlns=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">Test</multistatus>";

$xml3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus>Test</multistatus>";

//$xml->registerXPathNamespace("n", "http://iptc.org/std/NewsML/2003-10-10/");

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
//echo $xml;
foreach ($root->xpath('//multistatus') as $node) {
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}

Comment: Should combine our two answers mathieu's and mine. Should do the trick. And you need some sort of base container for those multistatus, unless you only plan on having the one node under it.

Comment: Indeed. I am simply trying to get the basics working. I've combined both, and it still does not appear to want to work.

Comment: I would say its because you are declaring your namespaces wrong. You need to use "C" (note its caps too) instead of "n". I'm not sure where you got the "n" from. Also, the default namespace needs to be registered, just assign a random letter, you can use "n" here if you wish.

Comment: I hate to be a bother, but I'd be very gracious if you could solve this problem for me: $xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus xmlns=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">Test</multistatus>";

$xml3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus>Test</multistatus>";

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);

$root->registerXPathNamespace("C", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav");
//echo $xml;
echo 'Test';
foreach ($root->xpath('//C:multistatus') as $node) {
    echo 'Test';
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}

Comment: Hmm. Print_r() shows the data, and SimpleXMLElement seems to eat the outermost tag. Interesting...

Comment: print_r shows the data because $xml is an array. If you want to iterate over the array, do something like `foreach($root as $node) { echo $node; }` after you have registered the namespaces. I'm not sure what you meant by "eat" it should just populate it into an array. Just noticed that you are printing $xml and not $root. I'm really confused now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your namespace using registerXPathNamespace()

This question should point in the right direction: [PHP simplexml: why does xpath stop working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352052/php-simplexml-why-does-xpath-stop-working)

Comment: $xml2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus xmlns=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\">Test</multistatus>";

$xml3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><multistatus>Test</multistatus>";

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
$root->registerXPathNamespace("n", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav");
//echo $xml;
foreach ($root->xpath('//n:multistatus') as $node) {
    echo $node . "<BR>";
}

Comment: Assuming I am declaring the namespace correctly, it does not appear to have any effect.