# XPath and Namespaces

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, kml

I've seen [various threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352052/php-simplexml-why-does-xpath-stop-working) on this matter but none have been able to help me. Basically, I'm interpreting a KML file with the intent of loading it in to a map but the namespaces are really screwing me up. Here's an example of the KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
     xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <Folder>
  <name>leeds primary schools (1 - 10)</name>
  <open>1<open>
  <Placemark>
      blah blah blah
  </Placemark>
  [etc etc etc]
```

So the idea is that I want to get all the Placemark elements on the page. So I'm using this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("n", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
$Placemarks = $xml->xpath("/n:Placemark");
```

And yet, I'm getting diddly-squit out, just an empty array. Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have always come around this by using `$xml->children()` - I've never bothered to actually understand how namespaces are supposed to work correctly with PHP..

Comment: Please make visible which of the various threads you've tried and what did not work specifically in your case? Please post all the codes of all your tries. Additionally I have to add: Why do you think should your code work? Even without taking namespaces into account it would not work, there are no such elements you ask for in that axis.

Answer (score 1):

> $Placemarks = $xml->xpath("/n:Placemark");

This tries to select the *top element* named "`n:Placemark`".

However, the top element isn't a "`Placemark`" -- it is a "`klm`"

**Solution**:

You want:

```
$Placemarks = $xml->xpath("/*/n:Folder/n:Placemark");
```